# videojs in Chrome: how to make a video starts where I choose?

Tags: video.js

I am playing with video.js. Here is my code:

```
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video.min.js"></script>

<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"
  controls autoplay preload="auto" width="1300" height="800"
  data-setup='{}'>
 <source src="/test.webm" type="video/webm" />
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

The above code was literally copied from the tool's website (except the video and autoplay):

http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html

My movie is played in both Chrome and Firefox. If I want to see something later in the movie, I am able to drag the dot in the progress bar to the point I want and the movie starts just there. However, when doing so in Chrome I got error:

> A network problem caused the media download to fail part-way.

Comment: Something like this is usually to do with the video file itself or how it's being served. Can you add an absolute URL to the file rather than "/test.webm"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript

```
videojs("last", {}, function () {
                var myplayer = this;
                myplayer.currentTime(s); // s being to time in second you want
                                }
```

Remove the data-setup attribute from the html tag and put what you had in second argument.

1. The first argument is the id of the video(be sure it has never been
   initialized)
2. The second is optional it is what you want to have in data-setup
3. The third is a function that you want to call when it is
   initialized.